# Each tasks added would have his own property

Tags: javascript

I have created a todo-apps with js but I have a problem :  when I am clicking on the check button to do someting or on the edit button or the time button all tasks are changed : for example when I click on the check button on « learn js » I want that just this task changed ( underline) but when I do that all my tasks become underline. I know this is a beginner question sorry. This is my HTML code :

```
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name..." id="Name">
<input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add Item" />
   <div class="choices">
     <p id="p"></p>
    </div>
  <button id="btn" type="submit"> Clear Items</button>
```

This is my JS code :

```
let clear  =  document.getElementById("btn");
let add = document.getElementById("addItem");
let choices = [];
let vide = document.getElementById('p');
var choice = document.getElementById("Name").value;
let invalid = document.getElementById("invalid");

function main() {
add.addEventListener('click', function() {
addItems();
})
}

function addItems() {
   choice = document.getElementById("Name").value;

    vide.innerHTML += choice;
   choices.push(choice);
   document.getElementById('p').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<i id="check" class="far fa-check-circle"></i>`);
   document.getElementById('p').insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', `<i id="null" class="far fa-times-circle"></i>`);
  document.getElementById('p').insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', `<i.     id="edit" class="far fa-edit"></i>`);
  vide.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<br/><br/>`);
   document.getElementById('p').classList.add('listClass');

   document.getElementById('check').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('p').classList.toggle("done");
            document.getElementById('check').classList.toggle('opacity');
    };
    document.querySelector('#null').onclick = function() {
      vide.innerHTML ='';
    };
document.getElementById('edit').onclick = function() {
  // I have not finished this part
 }
 }
 }

main();
```

This is a picture of the result : [image: picture]

Comment: HTML IDs *must* be unique. You keep adding `<i id="check" ...` and similar several times, resulting in duplicate IDs, and that is causing problems.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol How to resolve this ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depsite the fact that you have many mistakes(especially code redundancy) in your code, the main issue is that your `ID`s are not **unique** in the page.

As I said, the code is not that flexible to allow us building on it, so I took sometime to provide you a more modern, readable, performant solution (regarding yours of course !).

> The code is commented to allow you understand easily what I'm doing.

```js
// selecting the elements from the DOM
const todoList = document.getElementById("todo-list"),
  newTodoForm = document.getElementById("new-todo-form"),
  todoInp = document.getElementById("todo"),
  clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear"),
  choices = [],
  /**
   * createElement: a function that creates an HTML element with the specified attributes and events
   * @param nodeName (string) the HTML element tag name
   * @param opts (object) the attributes object which can contain :
   *   content: (object) an object to specify the element's content and it has two fields :
   *     html: (boolean) is the content should be inserted as HTML or a simple text. Defaults to false, pass true to treat the content as HTML
   *     value: (string) the actual content
   *   classList: (string) specifies a space-separated classes to be assigned to the element
   *   id: (string) the elemnt's ID
   *   data: (object) an object for the "data-TOKEN=VAL" attributes where each key (in camelCase) is the "TOKEN" and its value is the "VAL", example: {someDataOne: 'some value one', someDataTwo: 'some value two'} will be transformed into "data-some-data-one="some value one" data-some-data-two="some value two""
   *   events: (object) the keys are event names and the values are the events callbacks. Example {click: () => alert('clicked !')} 
   **/
  createElement = (nodeName, opts) => {
    // create the requested element
    const el = document.createElement(nodeName);
    // merge the options with the default ones
    opts = Object.assign({
        content: {
          value: "",
          html: !1
        },
        classList: "",
        id: "",
        data: {},
        events: {}
      },
      opts
    );
    // apply the classes if the "opts.classList" is not empty
    !!opts.classList && (el.classList = opts.classList);
    // apply the ID if the "opts.id" is not empty
    !!opts.id && (el.id = opts.id);
    // apply the content if the "opts.content.value" is not empty and check if we want the content to be treated as HTML
    !!opts.content.value &&
      (el[opts.content.html === !0 ? "innerHTML" : "textContent"] =
        opts.content.value);
    // apply the data-* if the "opts.data" is not empty
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(opts.data).length) {
      for (let p in opts.data)
        if (opts.data.hasOwnProperty(p)) el.dataset[p] = opts.data[p];
    }
    // assign the events if the "opts.events" is not empty
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(opts.events).length) {
      for (let p in opts.events)
        if (opts.events.hasOwnProperty(p))
          el.addEventListener(p, opts.events[p]);
    }
    // return the created element after applying the requested attributes and events 
    return el;
  },
  /*
   * a function that generates a list-item template (HTML code that contains the todo text, buttons for edit, delete and so on...)
   * @param txt (string) the todo text
   */
  todoItemTpl = txt => {
    // "item" is the list-item wrapper that contains all the buttons and todo text for only one todo item
    // as you can see, we're using the "createElement" function so the code doesn't get redundant and also it become more readable and flexible
    const item = createElement("div", {
        classList: "todo-item row col-12 py-2 px-0 m-0 my-1 align-items-center"
      }),
      // the "p" element that shows the todo text
      txtWrapper = createElement("p", {
        content: {
          value: txt
        },
        classList: "todo-text col-auto m-0"
      }),
      // a wrapper for the options (delete, edit and check) buttons of a todo item
      btnsWrapper = createElement("div", {
        classList: "todo-btns col-auto"
      }),
      // an array that holds the 3 option buttons so later we can loop through it and append each button to "btnsWrapper"
      // every button here has its click event so the browser won't get confused which todo item should it alter
      // !!: the edit functionality is not implemented it simply prints some text to the console when the edit button is clicked
      optionBtns = [
        createElement("button", {
          content: {
            value: '<i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>',
            html: !0
          },
          classList: "option-btn check-btn ml-1",
          events: {
            click: function() {
              this.closest('div.todo-item').classList.add('finished');
              this.disabled = !0;
            }
          }
        }),
        createElement("button", {
          content: {
            value: '<i class="far fa-edit"></i>',
            html: !0
          },
          classList: "option-btn edit-btn ml-1",
          events: {
            click: function() {
              console.log('Edit functionnality not yet implemented !');
            }
          }
        }),
        createElement("button", {
          content: {
            value: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>',
            html: !0
          },
          classList: "option-btn del-btn ml-1",
          events: {
            click: function() {
              const todoItem = this.closest('div.todo-item'),
                txt = todoItem.querySelector('.todo-text').textContent;
              todoItem.remove();
              choices.splice(choices.indexOf(txt), 1);
            }
          }
        })
      ];
    // append the option buttons to the buttons wrapper
    optionBtns.forEach((b) => btnsWrapper.appendChild(b));
    // append the todo text to the todo-item
    item.appendChild(txtWrapper);
    // append the option buttons wrapper text to the todo-item
    item.appendChild(btnsWrapper);
    // return the newly created todo-item
    return item;
  };

// listen for the form submission
newTodoForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  // store the trimmed input (the todo name) value
  const inpVal = todoInp.value.trim();
  // prevent form submission to disable page reload
  e.preventDefault();
  // stop execution if the todo item name is empty
  if (!inpVal) return;
  // if the todo text is not empty then :
  // append the entered value to the "choices" array
  choices.push(inpVal);
  // append the todo-item to the todo list (that is initially empty) using "todoItemTpl" function and by passing the entered value for the todo name
  todoList.appendChild(todoItemTpl(inpVal));
  // finnaly, empty up the todo name input field 
  todoInp.value = "";
});

// listen for the click event of the clear button
// when clicked, remove all the todo-items and empty up the "choices" array
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', () => (todoList.innerHTML = '', choices.length = 0));
```

```css
// styling for the demo, nothing fancy !
.todo-list * {
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
}

.todo-list {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.todo-list .todo-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}

.todo-list .todo-item.finished {
  background-color: #65d4a8;
}

.todo-list .todo-item.finished .todo-text {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!-- importing Bootsrap and Font-Awesome -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- some transformations to use Bootsrap's classes -->
<div class="todo-form-wrapper">
  <form action="#" id="new-todo-form">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." id="todo">
    <button type="submit" value="Add Item">Add</button>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- the todo list wrapper is initially empty -->
<div id="todo-list" class="todo-list row m-0"></div>
<button id="clear" type="button">Clear Items</button>
```

> Eventhough the code looks good, I don't recommand using it in production as it has some issues, it doesn't support old browsers like IE for example.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are adding all the contents inside one single - p - tag and when you change the class- i.e: toggling the class of that - p - tag to "done", it is getting applied to all inner texts.

You need separate wrapper for each task assertion to handle this problem.

Comment: how to do this ??